# Not enough values to unpack - despite length of the list being checked

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm using Python 3.6 to read a csv file. Every line in the csv file represents a varying number of 3D points in the format `x1,y1,z1;x2,y2,z2;...;xn,yn,zn`, i.e. every point is separated from the others with a semicolon, and coordinates of the same point are separated by commas.

My full code is as follows

```py
f = open(FILENAME, 'r')

def next_line():
    for line in f:
        yield line

def value_reader():
    line = next(next_line())
    for point in line.split(';'):
        splitted = point.split(',')
        if(len(splitted) != 3):
            continue
        for x,y,z in point.split(','):
            #... do something with x y z
```

However, the Python interpreter gives this error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

(of course, referring to the last line of the code I have included here)

I have tried printing all the values I'm processing, together with their type and found nothing unexpected (`point` is a `string`, `splitted` is a `list`, everything contains the appropriate number of values).
I'm pretty sture this is something stupid but after 1 hour of web searches I have found nothing useful... what am I missing? The length check should be more than enough to guarantee proper unpacking, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for x,y,z in point.split(',')
```

should be

```
x,y,z = point.split(',')
```

`point.split` creates a list, containing values the three values. If you do `for ... in point.split()`, then you will have three iterations of this loop. First with `x`, then with `y`, then with `z`

Comment: I see, thank you! To clarify matters to future readers: ``for x,y,z in point.split(',')`` expects every element in the list to contain three values (x,y,z).

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the generator is rather flawed.

Let's have a file with these contents:

```
x1,y1,z1;x2,y2,z2;x9,y9,z9
x3,y3,z3;x4,y4,z4;x8,y8,z8
```

...then...

```
FILENAME = '/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt'

def points(filename):
    with open(filename) as data:
        for line in data:
            for group in line.rstrip().split(';'):
                yield group.split(',')

for x, y, z in points(FILENAME):
    print(x, y, z)
```

**Output:**

```
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
x9 y9 z9
x3 y3 z3
x4 y4 z4
x8 y8 z8
```

Comment: I don't understand the point you are trying to make: why is my use of the generator flawed?

Comment: @Smartops You recreate the generator every time you call next(next_line()). It will work but is not the right way to use a generator

Comment: Ah thanks for the heads up! If I were to make minimal changes to my code, would ``for line in next_line()`` as the first line of value_reader() be more efficient?

Comment: @Smartops Yes - that would be much better. Also consider opening and closing the file in your next_line() function/generator